# netCDF4-python grid coordinates CDO failure

Tags: python, grid, netcdf, cdo-climate

I am using netCDF4-python to create netCDF4 files.

To create a dimensional variable:

```
createDimension
createVariable
```

To create other variables:

```
createVariable(dset.name, dset.dtype, dims)
```

It works well with panoply or ncdump, but when examined with

```
cdo sinfo
```

Grid coordinates shows "generic" instead of "lonlat", and unsurprisingly cdo cant subset the dataset:

```
cdo sellonlatbox (Abort): Unsupported grid type!
```

Does anyone here know the solution? Thanks,

-- Jay

Comment: Can you reproduce it with a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Also please share cdo version you are using.

Comment: cdo version: 1.6.8

Comment: I will try. The issue is, the file created by netCDF4-python does not have the  lonlat grid required by CDO.